# Angular subscribe inside of foreach not returning a promise

Tags: angular, typescript

I am doing a row by row update inside a `foreach` statement. I need to wait until all items in the `foreach` loop have been updated then I need to do some finalizing. This method below works as far as the service but the "wait.then" never gets hit. Is there a better way to do this?

```
var wait = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.myArray.Items.forEach(t => {
    this.service.UpdateItems(t).subscribe(
      () => {},
      err => this.alert(err),
      () => this.app.tick(),
    );
  });
});
wait.then(() => {
  // Wait until the foreach finished
  console.log(complete);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use Promises. You can do something like this, using [**`forkJoin`**](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin):

```
const sources = this.myArray.Items.map(item => {
  return this.service.UpdateItems(item).pipe(
    tap({
      complete: () => this.app.tick(), // not sure for what you're using this
      error: err => this.alert(err),
    }),
  );
});

forkJoin(sources)
  .pipe(finalize(() => console.log('do something')))
  .subscribe();
```

Comment: Yea that app.tick() is for changedetection  In development mode, `tick()` also performs a second change detection cycle to ensure that no
     * further changes are detected. If additional changes are picked up during this second cycle,
     * bindings in the app have side-effects that cannot be resolved in a single change detection
     * pass.

Comment: @TerranceJackson got it. Maybe it just works if instead of call `this.app.tick()` on every update, only in forkJoin's `finalize`? I guess that would be less expensive.